# Problema al cargar libreria PHPExcel con load

Tags: php, jquery, html5

Cuando cargo mi archivo Prueba.php desde el href funciona sin problema, cuando lo cargo desde un load ya no funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero de esta manera ya no, y lo hago asi porque necesito pasar valores antes de cargar el Excel.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Prueba.php
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Funcion `cargarPagina()`

```
function cargaPagina(pagina) {

    var opcion = document.getElementById("opcion").value;

    $('body').css('background', '#fafafa');

    $('#' + opcion).toggle();
    $('#contenido').toggle();
    $('#opcion').val('contenido');

    $('#frmContenido').load(pagina);

}
```

Comment: Comprueba que las rutas son correctas al llamar a la página desde el archivo **js** donde defines la función `cargaPagina();`

Comment: Gracias por responder Cifu, todo esta cargando bien parece que el problema es cuando quiere crear el archivo excel : $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');

Comment: Fíjate en como está en el código de esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066659/fatal-error-class-phpexcel-iofactory-not-found-in-phpexel a ver si te ayuda en algo, el solo le pasa un parámetro a la función donde supuestamente te da el error

Comment: El problema ocurre con la sintaxis save('php://output'); de modo que lo estoy cargando, porque si la reemplazo enviando una ruta especifica si lo hace : $salida='c:\Users\Ltsystem\Downloads/Comprobacion.xls';
        $objWriter->save($salida);  pero de la primera forma me abria la descarga en el pie de mi navegador como cuando descarga cualquier archivo

Comment: Puede ser que tengas alguna cabecera de más o incorrecta, también puede ser la versión de php que tengas en tu servidor, por lo demás no se me ocurre más

Comment: Gracias Cifu de todas maneras aun sigo investigando, parece que al cargar con LOAD esta esperando una cadena y no un buffer que es lo que esta enviando el $objwriter->save('php://output');

Comment: Gracias Cifu por el apoyo la sintaxis para escribir con jquery es diferente dejo el link donde encontre la solucion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701981/phpexcel-download-using-ajax-call